# Добавление стилей при наведении

Tags: javascript, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы при наведении на определенную `.card` у `.fastview`, `.backet` и `.click` убирался класс `.hide`. Смог написать только

```
$(function() {
  $(".card").mouseover(function() {
    $(".basket, .click, .fastview").removeClass("hide");
  });
  $(".card").mouseout(function() {
    $(".basket, .click, .fastview").addClass("hide");
  })
})
```

в результате чего класс `.hide` убирается на всех `.card`, а надо только на той, на которую наводишь. помогите кто чем может)

Comment: Нужен кусок кода для конкретной помощи. Хотя бы один блок.

Comment: .card:hover приведет к той же проблеме, о которой я спрашивал, можно было каждую  карту назвать по-своему, например .card1, .card2 и тд, и пришлось бы писать .card1:hover, .card2:hover, а если карт таких 100? с ума можно сойти

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете получить карточку, на которую навели курсор, вот так:

```
$(this)
```

Затем можно воспользоваться методом [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) чтобы найти в этой карточке объекты, стили которых нужно изменить.

```
$(function() {
  $(".card").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find(".basket, .click, .fastview").removeClass("hide");
  });
  $(".card").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find(".basket, .click, .fastview").addClass("hide");
  });
});
```

Comment: дай бог вам здоровья:D помогло)